# Use "Ctrl+A" To Select All and Delete Contents of Input Field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating an input field for social security numbers, and I am having an issue with the functionality of the input field. I would like to be able to press "Ctrl + A" - or "Command + A" on Mac - to select the content of the input field and then delete it. I am unable to do that on Windows 10 with Chrome. Any ideas on what to modify to allow for this behavior?

Here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tel-formating-forked-3uz9q?file=/src/App.js

And here is the relevant code:

```js
//App.js

import React, { useRef, useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ phone: "" });
  const cursorPos = useRef(null);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const keyIsDelete = useRef(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    cursorPos.current = e.target.selectionStart;
    let val = e.target.value;
    cursorPos.current -= (
      val.slice(0, cursorPos.current).match(/-/g) || []
    ).length;
    let r = /(\D+)/g,
      first3 = "",
      next3 = "",
      last4 = "";
    val = val.replace(r, "");
    let newValue;
    if (val.length > 0) {
      first3 = val.substr(0, 3);
      next3 = val.substr(3, 2);
      last4 = val.substr(5, 4);
      if (val.length > 5) {
        newValue = first3 + "-" + next3 + "-" + last4;
      } else if (val.length > 3) {
        newValue = first3 + "-" + next3;
      } else if (val.length < 4) {
        newValue = first3;
      }
    } else newValue = val;
    setState({ phone: newValue });
    for (let i = 0; i < cursorPos.current; ++i) {
      if (newValue[i] === "-") {
        ++cursorPos.current;
      }
    }
    if (newValue[cursorPos.current] === "-" && keyIsDelete.current) {
      cursorPos.current++;
    }
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    const allowedKeys = [
      "Control",
      "Delete",
      "ArrowLeft",
      "ArrowRight",
      "Backspace",
      "Home",
      "End",
      "Enter",
      "Tab"
    ];
    if (e.key === "Delete") {
      keyIsDelete.current = true;
    } else {
      keyIsDelete.current = false;
    }
    if ("0123456789".includes(e.key) || allowedKeys.includes(e.key)) {
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.selectionStart = cursorPos.current;
      inputRef.current.selectionEnd = cursorPos.current;
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type="text"
        value={state.phone}
        placeholder="SSN"
        onChange={handleChange}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "Meta" for mac(instead of control) and "a" for detecting what actually happends after pressing control to your allowedKeys array.
The issue was that even control was allowed the "a" key itself not.

```
 const allowedKeys = [
      "Control",
      "Delete",
      "ArrowLeft",
      "ArrowRight",
      "Backspace",
      "Home",
      "End",
      "Enter",
      "Tab",
      "Meta",
      "a"
    ];
```